# Difficulty in understanding this recursion sequence for merging K sorted Lists

Tags: python, recursion, merge, linked-list

I have been trying to understand the sequence of this recursion for this leetcode question I found a solution too. I understand the merge function but I don't understand the recursion that happens on mergeKLists function. Help would be appreciated. Please be as descriptive as possible in showing me the calls and the return that leads to a final merged linked list. * I understand the merge function so no need to explain that one.

```
def mergeKLists(self, lists):
    if not lists:
        return 
    if len(lists) == 1:
        return lists[0]
    mid = len(lists)//2
    l = self.mergeKLists(lists[:mid])
    r = self.mergeKLists(lists[mid:])
    return self.merge(l, r)

def merge(self, l, r):
    dummy = cur = ListNode(0)
    while l and r:
        if l.val < r.val:
            cur.next = l
            l = l.next
        else:
            cur.next = r
            r = r.next
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = l or r
    return dummy.next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mergeKLists` merges lists in pairs so they're more equal in size when merged, which means we're working on smaller sub-lists, so we avoid the uneven O(a+b) time complexity of merging two lists of highly uneven length. The recursion pattern is similar to merge sort.

Unless there's a proven-by-profiling performance benefit, and a real world need for that extra performance, I'd reject this in a code review and tell the author to use a for loop instead. I suspect a for loop could be faster in practice, even though there divide-and-conquer style recursion that they used is faster in theory.

If performance really matters and we have huge lists, it's even faster to write a single merge sort step that merges k lists directly, by walking all k lists in sync and copying the values in order, for O(sum(map(length,k))) time complexity of that last merge step. Of course that would be dominated by the time to sort each list first at O(n log n) (if we use a comparison-based sorting algorithm).

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying. I am trying to understand this recursion, because I am following it step by step like on a piece of paper, but I don't get how it leads to the last sorted merged list. Maybe its the code; maybe im dumb lol, but if you have time, could you clarify how the calls lead to that one last linked list. Like with a short example. I would appreciate that so much

Comment: Add some debug prints to the start of each function, showing the arguments it was called with. Then run with a small input.

Comment: Ok I will search how to do that. That might answer my question